# 3D pie chart appear like a normal chart

Tags: php, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to create a 3D pie chart using ObHighchartsBundle ,but instead of 3d the pie appear normal pie?  I dont know why!! I have added the options3d and depth field

This how it looks:

[image]

**Contoller.php**

```
public function chartPie(Survey $servey)
{

    $center= $servey ->getCenter();
    $form = $servey ->getForm();
    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('containerpie');
   $ob->chart->type('pie');
    $ob->chart->options3d(array('enabled' => true,'alpha'=> '45','beta'=> null));
    $ob->plotOptions->pie(array( 
        'depth' => '25',
        'allowPointSelect'  => true,
        'cursor'    => 'pointer',
        'dataLabels'    => array('enabled' => true , 'format'=> '{point.name}'),
        'showInLegend'  => true
    ));



    $ob->title->text('Emploee');



    $data = array(
        array('Engineer', $form->getNbEngineer()),
        array('Agents ', $form->getNbAgents ()),
        array('Technicien', $form->getNbTechnicien()),
        array(‘Laborer’,$form->getNbLaborer ())
);

    $ob->series(array(array('type' => 'pie','name' => 'Browser', 'data' => $data)));
    return $ob;
}
```

**ChartingClass.php :**

```
$containerpie=$chart->chartPie($servey);
$html =  $this->render('AppBundle :Charting:index.html.twig',array(
        'survey' =>$survey,
        'containerpie' =>$containerpie

    ));


    return $html;
}
```

**Twig :**

```
<div id="containerpie" ></div>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    {{ chart(containerpie) }}
</script>
```

Comment: Looking at your js includes you have jquery after highcharts - jquery should be first. also you have mixed highcharts versions - you are loading highcharts.js 4.1.8 but the highcharts-3d.js is most likely 5.0.12. Try using all the same version of highcharts files and have jquery loaded first.

Comment: thank you very much it's indeed a version problem